# Flutter: How to prevent the keyboard from overlaying the content in CustomScrollView/SliverToBoxAdapter?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter I have a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar` and a `SliverToBoxAdapter` which contains several widgets including some `TextFormField`s and a `ElevatedButton`.

How can I prevent the keyboard from overlaying the content of the `SliverToBoxAdapter`? Basically, I want the scroll position to always be at max extent by default.

**Expected behaviour:**

[image]

[image]

**Current behaviour:**

[image]

[image]

**Code:**

```
class MyHomePage extends HookWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 400,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text(
                'Lorem ipsum',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              background: Image(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/16288133/pexels-photo-16288133.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2'
                ),
              ),
            )
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text('My form'),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
                    labelText: 'Form field',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  // Space to enforce scrolling
                  height: 300,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                   onPressed: () {},
                   child: const Text('Submit'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push content up when focus is on TextField and keyboard opens in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70364604/how-to-push-content-up-when-focus-is-on-textfield-and-keyboard-opens-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using a `ScrollController` enables the expected behaviour regarding the scroll position to be at max extent. But the keyboard still overlays the content (below) the form field, which still needs to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You have to disable the scaffold resize on keyboard appear.

Add  `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` in scaffold.

Example:

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: ...
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried adding `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to the `Scaffold`. This does not change the behaviour. At least for my provided example.